# Select statement for following situation

Tags: sql, oracle

```
|   Column id         |     status       |
|          1          |      Accept      |
|          1          |     Shipped      |
|          1          |     Received     |
|          2          |      Accept      |
|          2          |     Received     |
|          3          |      Accept      |
|          3          |     Shipped      |
|          3          |     Received     |
```

I want those IDs in output whose status haven't been shipped but have been received.
(NOT SHIPPED BUT RECEIVED)(id 2)

Comment: Please correct your formatting, as it's difficult to understand the table structure you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
select column_id
from table
where status = 'Received'
minus
select column_id
from table
where status = 'Shipped'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get `id` and corresponding `status`

```
select *
from
(select id ,listagg(status,',') within group(order by id) status_concat 
from table
group by id) CTE
where CTE.status_concat='Accept,Received';
```

if no need to hard code and if the status is only these 3 `('Accept','Received','Shipped')`, below query will also work

```
select id
from
 (select count(*) CNT,id  from table 
 group by id) CTE
where CTE.CNT=2;
```